# Python Pandas Fast Way to Divide Row Value by Previous Value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to calculate daily bond returns from clean prices based on the logarithm of the bond price in t divided by the bond price in t-1. So far, I calculate it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#create example data
col1 = np.random.randint(0,10,size=10)
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["col1"] = col1
df["result"] = [0]*len(df)
#slow computation
for i in range(len(df)):
    if i == 0:
        df["result"][i] = np.nan
    else:
        df["result"][i] = np.log(df["col1"][i]/df["col1"][i-1])
```

However, since I have a large sample this takes a lot of time to compute. Is there a way to improve the code in order to make it faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) by `col1` column with [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html) for division:

```
df["result1"] = np.log(df["col1"].div(df["col1"].shift()))
#alternative
#df["result1"] = np.log(df["col1"] / df["col1"].shift())
print (df)
   col1    result   result1
0     5       NaN       NaN
1     0      -inf      -inf
2     3       inf       inf
3     3  0.000000  0.000000
4     7  0.847298  0.847298
5     9  0.251314  0.251314
6     3 -1.098612 -1.098612
7     5  0.510826  0.510826
8     2 -0.916291 -0.916291
9     4  0.693147  0.693147
```

I test both solutions:

```
np.random.seed(0)

col1 = np.random.randint(0,10,size=10000)
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':col1})


In [128]: %timeit df["result1"] = np.log(df["col1"] / df["col1"].shift())
865 µs ± 139 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [129]: %timeit df.assign(result=lambda x: np.log(x.col1.pct_change() + 1))
1.16 ms ± 11.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)


In [130]: %timeit df["result1"] = np.log(df["col1"].pct_change() + 1)
1.03 ms ± 14.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

---

```
np.random.seed(0)

col1 = np.random.randint(0,10,size=100000)
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':col1})

In [132]: %timeit df["result1"] = np.log(df["col1"] / df["col1"].shift())
3.7 ms ± 189 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [133]: %timeit df.assign(result=lambda x: np.log(x.col1.pct_change() + 1))
6.31 ms ± 545 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


In [134]: %timeit df["result1"] = np.log(df["col1"].pct_change() + 1)
3.75 ms ± 269 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast reply, this implementation works perfectly and a lot faster.

Comment: Why use `.div()` and `.shift()` when `pct_change()` exists?

Comment: The time duration differences are just due to different indexing and column assignment methods. `pct_change()` will be faster, other things being equal.

Comment: You should also take memory complexity into account - you're creating two new `Series` objects here, where one is sufficient.

Comment: @gshpychka - ya, performance is better like `assign` solution.

Comment: Performance is not just speed (which is roughly equal between the approahces) - take memory complexity into account as well - no need to create two new Series objects.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use multiple functions, use [`Series.pct_change()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.pct_change.html):

```py
df = df.assign(
    result=lambda x: np.log(x.col1.pct_change() + 1)
)
print(df)
   col1    result
0     3       NaN
1     5  0.510826
2     8  0.470004
3     7 -0.133531
4     9  0.251314
5     1 -2.197225
6     1  0.000000
7     2  0.693147
8     7  1.252763
9     0      -inf
```

Answer (score -1):

This should be a much faster way to get the same results:

```
df["result_2"] = np.log(df["col1"] / df["col1"].shift())
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJ9JQ.png]

Comment: There is already an answer with this solution.